# Can I submit a field value as an array with extjs?

Tags: java, arrays, extjs

On my form I have a textarea which calls for a list of words. e.g. word1,word2,word3 etc. The user can put as many words as they wish. My application gets this entry back as a single string, "word1,word2,word3" and to convert it to an array I have to do myString.split(",").

I was wondering if it is possible to set up the form so that extjs knows it should convert this to an array when it submits the data? Something like:

```
var myField = {
            xtype : 'textarea',
            fieldLabel : 'Words',
            name : 'words',
            type: 'array'
    }
```

edit: I'd also be happy with having some kind of onSubmit function that sets the value of the field to an array client side before it is sent

Comment: How exactly do you suppose to send an array to server during submit?

Comment: Probably to send it formatted as a JSON array instead of a string. e.g. {"words": ["word1","word2"]} instead of just {"words":"word1,word2"}. I don't know any other way it could be done

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use extjs 4 and higher I would suggest the following:

Override `Ext.form.field.TextArea` field and implement it's `getModelData( )` function to be something like this:

```
getModelData: function() {
    var me = this,
    data = null;
    if (!me.disabled && !me.isFileUpload()) {
        data = {};
        data[me.getName()] = me.getValue().split(",");
    }
    return data;
}
```

This will allow Ext to properly interpret your field's model value as a string array. Then the model of your form will contain proper array for your field.
You may call `getFieldValues()` for your basic form to return corresponding json to send it to server, or you may use Ext MVC functions to work with form's model.